# Eclipse showing methods

Tags: eclipse, ide

Is there a way in Eclipse to show the methods in a drop down on top of your screen? Like they do in visual studio.
[image: example]

I know I can press Ctrl-O 
I just find the visual studio way handy.

Comment: Well... no, there's no way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alt-Shift-B** will bring up the Breadcrumb, which might be close to what you're looking for. If you click the arrow icons you'll get dropdowns for the packages, classes or methods.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there is no exact same way in eclipse you might find the feature to expand classes in the Package Explorer useful:

[image]